# how to share cookie'es across mobile web application and main web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile-website

I have a mobile version web application of my website with domain, 
main website   http://hello.world.com
mobile website http://m.hello.world.com

if the user logs into my mobile website and user visits main web application he should be logged into the main website as well and viceversa. 
i am setting login cokkies.

i tried to set the path like:

```
HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, isPersistent);
cookie.Path = "/";
```

but didn't work. Let me know how can i solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can share cookies across subdomains, by using this technique

[ASP.NET Subdomain Cookie (parent and one subdomain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172490/asp-net-subdomain-cookie-parent-and-one-subdomain)

Effectively you need to add

```
    cookie.Domain = ".world.com";
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
```

Comment: I have changed the host file of developing machine to m.local.hello.my and local.hello.my for testing purpose and 
setting the cookie.Domain = ".hello.my"; Is there any mistake, doing something like this. this is not working.

Comment: Haven't tested myself, but should work. Have you cleared all your cookies for all .hello.my domains to start with?

Comment: yeah i have cleared all the cookies. but the fact is that i am not able to logout, its not clearing that cookies.

Comment: i got solution from this
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SingleSignon.aspx?display=Mobile

Comment: Ah, I assumed your subdomain was hosted on the same server. The machinekey stuff should be unnecessary if that was the case

Answer (score 0):

Then you create a cookie it's, by default, is associated with current domain i.e. `hello.world.com` and `m.hello.world.com` and retrieved also, by domain. You should look into setting [Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property of a cookie the you create and read them.