# passing session variable from without www to with www

Tags: session, web

Session variable is not passing between the urls **without www** and **with www**
I have implemented url rewriting in my website.

Example:
I want to pass Session["hashtable"] from   http://domain.com/product.aspx page to    http://www.domain.com/shoppingcart.aspx

Session is not passing between these urls,
tried a lot of settings in web.config adding httpcontext defaultname=.domain.com
still not working.

Any solution for this, great helpful for me.

Thanks in advance

Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I've never done anything like this myself, but according to this question and answer, [How can I share a session across multiple subdomains in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273732/how-can-i-share-a-session-across-multiple-subdomains-in-asp-net), you should be able to do this by adding this line to your web.config file:

```
<httpCookies domain=".usa.com"/>
```

Again, I haven't tried it. But it makes sense, I think.

I'm viewing your `domain.com` as being a "subdomain" of the same as `www.domain.com`. This isn't *really* true in a technical sense, but in a lot of cases I've seen it work that way anyway, so I'm hoping this will be one of those cases.

**Edit:**

I just came across this post, [ASP.NET sharing session across multiple wildcard subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646909/asp-net-sharing-session-across-multiple-wildcard-subdomains), which leads me to think this might not actually work, after all. Let me know if it doesn't and I'll delete this answer.

**Edit 2:**

Okay, I'm searching and finding tons and tons of people with this very problem. It *sounds* like it might just not be doable. That is, these people don't have any answers whatsoever. So it could just be that people who ask this are super unlucky, or it could be that it's just some little-known solution, or it could be that it's impossible. Thus, I'm adding in my comment from above here, and calling it a part of my "answer."

Just in the interest of good SEO practice for this site which, from the paths you provided, appears to be retail-related, you should probably just redirect all requests at any point to your `www.` domain, before you even set the session variables. If you can't do that, for instance if your www. root is not the same as your empty one (Which you should change anyway, for users' sakes), spin up another subdomain and point all requests to that. Then you'll have two domains at the same level, and the first solution I posted should handle that.