# Servicestack hosting on subdomain and authenticating from main domain

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

> I am creating one web app in asp.net MVC with identity (OWIN)
>   framework. Now it will be hosted in one domain lets say  domain.com
>
> Now i want to host servicestack on sub domain lets say
>   service.domain.com
>
> Now any user who login in domain.com with username and password and if
>   it success then i want to authenticate servicestack too so that all
>   services with [Authenticate] attribute will work.
>
> The primary objective of hosting servicestack on subdomain is to make
>   code independent for database side.
>
> And i can easily call this REST api in my future Android and iOS app.
>
> Is it something wrong i am doing?

I have tried with code provided by mythz  but now i get this error
[AuthKey required to use: HS256](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1PTc.png)

My MVC code is (running on: localhost:51055)

```
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

    switch (result)
    {
           case SignInStatus.Success:
           {
                var jwtProvider = new JwtAuthProvider();

                        var header = JwtAuthProvider.CreateJwtHeader(jwtProvider.HashAlgorithm);
                        var body = JwtAuthProvider.CreateJwtPayload(new AuthUserSession
                        {
                            UserAuthId = user.Id,
                            DisplayName = user.NameSurname,
                            Email = user.Email,
                            IsAuthenticated = true,
                        },
                            issuer: jwtProvider.Issuer,
                            expireIn: jwtProvider.ExpireTokensIn,
                            audience: jwtProvider.Audience,
                            roles: new[] { "TheRole" },
                            permissions: new[] { "ThePermission" });

                        var jwtToken = JwtAuthProvider.CreateJwt(header, body, jwtProvider.GetHashAlgorithm());

                        var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:52893/");
                        client.SetTokenCookie(jwtToken);

          }
    }
```

error occured on this statement `jwtProvider.GetHashAlgorithm()`

Any my servicestack code is (running on: localhost:52893)

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("MVC 4", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                RestrictAllCookiesToDomain = "localhost",
                HandlerFactoryPath = "api",
                DebugMode = true
            });

Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] {
                    new JwtAuthProviderReader(AppSettings) {
                        AuthKey = AesUtils.CreateKey(),
                        HashAlgorithm = "RS256"
                    },
                }));

            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
                    allowOriginWhitelist: new[] {
                        "http://localhost",
                        "http://localhost:51055"
                    },
                    allowCredentials: true,
                    allowedMethods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization, Wait, Accept, X-Requested-With, Put-Default-Position, Put-Before, If-Match, If-None-Match, Content-Range",
                    exposeHeaders: "Content-Range"
                ));

        }
}
```

Is something wrong i am doing?

Comment: Can you explain more details about this

Comment: This OK..  But if somebody logout in web then api also will do the same...  So user will feel irritating..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to integrate 2 different frameworks together by using Authentication from MVC (OWIN) with ServiceStack - an isolated framework that doesn't have any coupling or knowledge of OWIN or MVC's Authentication. This is further conflated by trying to transfer Authentication from one domain into a different framework on a different sub domain. Usually trying to try integrate Authentication between completely different frameworks is a difficult endeavor and requiring it to work across sub-domains adds even more complexity.

#### Storing an Authenticate User Session

With that said the 2 easiest solutions that can work is to store an authenticated UserSession in ServiceStack by serializing an `AuthUserSession` into the [location which ServiceStack expects](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#formatting-of-keys-used-in-cache-providers) by using the same [distributed Caching Provider](http://docs.servicestack.net/caching) configured on both MVC and ServiceStack Apps.

So you can configure [ServiceStack to use a Redis CacheClient](http://docs.servicestack.net/caching#redis) you can create and store a UserSession in MVC:

```
var session = new AuthUserSession {
    UserAuthId = userId,
    DisplayName = userName,
    Email = userEmail,
    IsAuthenticated = true,
};
```

Then save it using the [configured Redis Manager](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-client-managers) in MVC:

```
var sessionId = SessionExtensions.CreateRandomSessionId();
using (var redis = redisManager.GetClient())
{
    redis.Set($"urn:iauthsession:{sessionId}", session);
}
```

To get ServiceStack to use this Authenticated UserSession you need to configure the `ss-id` [Session Cookie Id](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#cookie-session-ids) with `sessionId` and since you want the client to send the same Cookie to sub-domain you need to configure the [Cookie to use a wildcard domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7591730/85785).

#### Using JWT

The alternative (and my preferred solution) that doesn't require sharing any infrastructure dependencies is to use a stateless JWT Token which encapsulates the Users Session in a JWT Token. To do this in MVC you would create a [JWT Token from an Authenticated User Session](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#creating-jwt-tokens-manually) which you can send to a ServiceStack AppHost [configured with the same JwtAuthProvider](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#stateless-auth-microservices).

Clients can then make Authenticated Requests by [sending JWT Tokens in the JWT Cookie](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#sending-jwt-using-cookies), i.e. sending the JWT Token in the `ss-tok` cookie which to work across sub-domains needs to be configured to use the same wildcard domain as above.

Comment: As you may know the primary objective to use servicestack is that my database side code resides in servicestack (hosted in sub domain). So that i can easily call this in my web, android, ios and window app. 

Currently i used servicestack.MVC in my asp.net mvc project. So when user signin and if success then it will authenticate servicestack too. and when user logout then i will logout too from servicestack.

Comment: @SohebRapati please read the [JWT documentation](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) carefully, your JwtAuthProvider is not properly configured and you need to use the **exact configuration** on both MVC and ServiceStack, i.e. you can't use an in memory `AesUtils.CreateKey()` as per the first paragraph in the JWT docs.

Comment: @SohebRapati If you're still unsure check out the [JwtAuthProviderTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/UseCases/JwtAuthProviderTests.cs) and [StatelessAuthTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Server.Tests/Auth/StatelessAuthTests.cs) for working examples.