# Preventing cookies sharing in the same domain in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have two sites in the same domain. This sites are sharing cookies across this domain. In web.config I have

```
<system.web>
 <authentication mode="none">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" />
 </authentication>
```

I can't predict the domain name too.

How to stop this?

Comment: how you separate the two domains ? (eg, the one is one.domain.com the other two.domain.com) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589630/sharing-asp-net-cookies-across-sub-domains

Comment: Possible duplicate also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out/2491686#2491686