# cookie domain getting changed, only one cookie with '.' one without

Tags: asp.net, cookies, httpcookie

I am explicitly setting a cookie domain so it is shared between the domain and a sub domain.  Think mysite.com and payment.mysite.com.  Sometimes I get two session cookies when I only have one specified.  When looking in firefox the domains on the cookies are different, one is "mysite.com" and the other is ".mysite.com"   how does this happen?  I am setting the domain to mysite.com but it is trimmed from one.

I am using asp.net.

Thanks

Comment: Here is an answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172490/asp-net-subdomain-cookie-parent-and-one-subdomain

Comment: i know how to share a cookie between two domains.  The problem is that the preceeding '.' is removed from one.  My title is unclear I suppose

Comment: or rather I set it to mysite.com, but occasionally I end up with two cookies.  one for mysite.com and one for .mysite.com

Comment: Make sure you use the same domain when setting the cookie on both sites to Response.Cookies("domain").Domain = ".mysite.com";

Comment: yeah, i could swear to it that I do and it is a browser thing.  I set a conditional breakpoint and it never gets hit

Answer (score 0):

It depens what you specify as a domain in setcookie function. Please take a look at the description in here http://php.net/setcookie.