# REST API Authentication with same origin policy and OAuth

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I am writing an API to be used by both my JavaScript app (same domain, API is at `api.example.com` and site at `example.com` and 3rd party developers (mobile, desktop, etc). Now I want to use OAuth but I have no idea how the workflow is when using both OAuth and using my application with the same origin policy.

How do I authenticate the user in my web app? When I send the username and password, can I check if the request came from my domain and then return the token? The token will be stored in a cookie and sent back to the server on every request. So there are 2 parts:

1. If the request came from my domain, just check for token else throw HTTP exception.
2. If not my domain, do OAuth authentication.

Is this possible? How do I go about setting this up in asp.net web API? (mainly the part about checking if the request is in the same domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that to log into your web app you're not using OAuth, but simply accept username and password and start a session? If so you don't really have to bother with OAuth for your own site.

Set up the session cookie to be valid across `*.example.com` and you should be able to validate that cookie both on `site.example.com` and `api.example.com`.

Example:

1. Request comes in to `api.example.com/verify_credentials.json`
2. Serve response if OAuth validation is successful.
3. If not, attempt Cookie validation - serve if successful
4. Return `402 Unauthorized` if both fail.

Here's a thread about sharing a cookie across sub domains: [ASP.NET Subdomain Cookie (parent and one subdomain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172490/asp-net-subdomain-cookie-parent-and-one-subdomain)