# Sharing Session state between apps using ASP.NET Session State Provider for Redis

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, redis, session-variables

apologies for the verbose title.  We want our apps to share Session State.  Here's the deal:

- apps x.pe.com and y.pe.com are using [ASP.NET Session State Provider for Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/) (aka RedisSessionStateProvider)
- user logs into x.pe.com, which does some calculations and writes `Session["UserStats"] = 23;` (or whatever) to Redis. All good so far.
- user then hits a page served by y.pe.com. Because both apps issue cookies with a domain of ".pe.com", the cookies from x.pe.com are sent along with the request to y.pe.com.
- hence the user is authorised on y.pe.com. Great.
- y.pe.com calls `var userStats = Session["UserStats"];` and this is where the problem is.

I poked around in redis and saw that the names of the keys being stored by x.pe.com are of the ilk `PE_usxuattjkpn1j4kprgnmthu3_Data`. Naturally this key will be known to x.pe.com but not y.pe.com so I strongly suspect that after `var userStats = Session["UserStats"];` , userStats will be null.

Two options seem to avail:

1. [Share session state across apps using ASP.NET_SessionId](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174338/1170932)
2. use machine key so that (somehow) [the two ASP.NET runtimes share session state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3855666/1170932)

Which is "best"?  I'm leaning towards getting 1. working since it "should just work" and is simple to understand.

Many thanks.