# How to redirect from one domain address to another domain address in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .htaccess, url

I have a website with two different domain.

1. us.site.com
2. usa.site.com

Now when user Click on Login 
It first check its country. According to country I want to redirect whole site on that url and that time it not again asks for account id and password. so i want to maintain these things but it should not visible in Url.

Please Suggest me any way to do this.
I don't want to use QueryString and Cookie

Comment: Basic idea as following. You can use cookies. On login, create a cookie for "site.com" having user information. When user redirects to for say login to usa.site.com, check the cookies in pageload. If you found the cookies read the cookies and convert it to session. Use session further to check loogged in user information.

Comment: Is there any otherway because cookies are not secure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer.
Basic idea as following. You can use cookies. On login, create a cookie for "site.com" having user information. When user redirects to for say login to usa.site.com, check the cookies in pageload. If you found the cookies read the cookies and convert it to session. Use session further to check loogged in user information.

Related question link,
[How can you keep a session across multiple subdomains in c# mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424307/how-can-you-keep-a-session-across-multiple-subdomains-in-c-sharp-mvc)

[How can I share a session across multiple subdomains in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273732/how-can-i-share-a-session-across-multiple-subdomains-in-asp-net?lq=1)

[Write cookies from subdomain and read from another subdomain without changing web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831605/write-cookies-from-subdomain-and-read-from-another-subdomain-without-changing-we?lq=1)

**To make cookie secure use encryption.**

Reference :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13665/HttpSecureCookie-A-Way-to-Encrypt-Cookies-with-ASP

[Encrypt cookies in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360839/encrypt-cookies-in-asp-net)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manishkdwivedi/encrypting-and-decrypting-cookies-in-Asp-Net-2-0/

Comment: I read the disadvantage of cookie that cookie are domain specific...In this case I have two different domains so can I read cookie value from one domain to another? I have tested your solution on local host..I created two localhost web applications and created cookie using js ..In this case when I write window.location="http://localhost :548741//Login.aspx" and when I read cookie on that webapplication I can read it ..but Is this solution also helpful to actual domains?

Comment: As in your question you are having two sub domains.  `us.site.com` and `usa.site.com`. Now your domain name is `site.com`.
If you are setting cookies for `site.com` then the cookies will be accessible from the sub domain `us.site.com` and `usa.site.com`

Comment: do you have some other technique? I don't want to use cookies and querystring

Answer (score 0):

Use `MD5/SHA Encryption` to store value in `cookie` and once you redirect to other page then use `decryption` `Algo` and use that cookie value.

It will solve your issue.. Check below link for reference - 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38951/How-To-Hash-Data-Using-MD-and-SHA

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14150/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Data-with-C
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12602/Using-MD-Encryption-with-C-and-MSSQL

Or you can use alternative way to store value in database `temp table`