# Mainting Session across multiple urls

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

Okay so I'm implementing a payment gateway in which the gateway is passed a url to return to after the payment is complete, eg. www.mywebapp.com/success.aspx. That page however, utilises a few of the session variables that may have been created.
Problem: If the user was using mywebapp.com (without www), and sessions were created, upon reaching the success page(with www), the sessions dont exist at that point and the application breaks. 
Any ideas to maintain either consistency with the urls or sessions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9424401/492258)

Comment: You should add a redirect rule so that all visitors go the non-www instance of your web application. That way you won't have any visitors in the www instance.