# asp forms auth cookie domain not being set

Tags: asp.net, cookies, iis-7

I'm trying to set the domain of the cookie to be mysite.net instead no matter what i do it sets the cookie to be server.mysite.net  The problem is I want to switch between subdomain so i can do server1.mysite.net server2.mysite.net.

Below is the line i'm specifying for the cookie.

```
<pre>
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="120"   domain="mysite.net" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" name=".ASPXAUTH" />
    </authentication>  
</pre>
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2088853/222427

And there you have it a weeks worth of work for one line in a web.config...